# Will google appengine legacy services based python2 standard runtime application continue to work after appcfg tool shutdown?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

One of our projects uses Memcache, Mail API, Task Queue, Cloud KMS V1, and other legacy app engine services for Python 2 (standard env). If we can build this project with gcloud, will this continue to work after August 30 (after appcfg build tool shutdown)?

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you deploy a new python2 app using gcloud,those legacy service will continue working as indicated in the documents [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache), [mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail), [taskqueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue). The only escenario in which those legacy service will not work is if you upgrade to python 3, which is actually recommended since python2 is no longer supported.

The recommendation is to migrate to python 3 as your runtime, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services) you can find more details about how to migrate each one of those legacy services (an others) when migrating to python 3.